# lottie animations is nil in ios

Tags: ios, swift, lottie

I'm trying to use Lottie animations inside my ios app but I can't get them to work. I've seen people use `LOTAnimationViews` but I can't import or use this class. I've added an Animation folder with my animations in.

ViewController:

```
class CardStackViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, NetworkManagerDelegate {
    ...
    private let animationView = AnimationView()
    ...

    ...
    func didFail(with error: Error) {
        if let animation = Animation.named("error", subdirectory: "Animations") {
            animationView.animation = animation
            animationView.loopMode = .loop
            view.addSubview(animationView)
            animationView.play()
        }
        print("---DIDFAIL WITH ERROR---", error.localizedDescription, error)
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above

```
import lottie
```

and give the view a frame

```
animationView.animation = animation
animationView.frame = ///
```

Comment: and this frame is a `CGRect` for example?

Answer (score 1):

If are want to achieve it using a storyboard, follow these steps:

1. Drag and drop a view in your View controller.
2. Change the class of the View to AnimationView and module to Lottie as shown below.

[image: Like this]

3. Now in your ViewController class, import Lottie and create an outlet like this:

   ```
   import Lottie

   class YourVC : UIViewController { 
   @IBOutlet weak var myAnimationView : AnimationView!
   }
   ```
4. Now in your ViewDidLoad function setup your animation like this:

   ```
   let animationToShow = Animation.named("yourAnimationFileNameWithoutJSONextension")
   myAnimationView.animation = animationToShow
   myAnimationView.animationSpeed = 1.0
   myAnimationView.loopMode = .loop
   myAnimationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
   myAnimationView.play()
   ```

Done!